# npm install canvas on FreeBSD 10.1

Tags: node.js, npm, freebsd

Can anyone tell what's up with this? `cairo-1.12.18_1,2` is installed. I've tried `export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/libdata/pkgconfig` to no avail:

```
# uname -a
FreeBSD test 10.1-RELEASE FreeBSD 10.1-RELEASE #0 r274401: Tue Nov 11 21:02:49 UTC 2014
# npm install canvas
/
> canvas@1.1.6 install /usr/home/www/myapp/node_modules/canvas
> node-gyp rebuild

./util/has_cairo_freetype.sh: line 4: pkg-config: command not found
gyp: Call to './util/has_cairo_freetype.sh' returned exit status 0. while trying to load binding.gyp
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:343:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:12)
gyp ERR! System FreeBSD 10.1-RELEASE
gyp ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/home/www/myapp/node_modules/canvas
gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.35
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v1.0.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! FreeBSD 10.1-RELEASE
npm ERR! argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "canvas"
npm ERR! node v0.10.35
npm ERR! npm  v2.1.18
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! canvas@1.1.6 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the canvas@1.1.6 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the canvas package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls canvas
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /usr/home/www/myapp/npm-debug.log
```

Comment: I assume you have the `pkgconf` package installed?

Comment: Thank you -- I didn't know I needed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the `pkgconf` package. (Moving my comment to an answer so you can mark it correct for the benefit of future viewers.)